# RSelenium: Error while downloading files with Chrome

Tags: r, web-scraping, download, rselenium

I am using RSelenium to download a number of .xls files. I was able to get a somewhat passable solution using the following code to set up the server, which specifies not to create a pop-up when I click on the download link and where to download the file to. However, without fail, once I download the 101st file (saved as "report (100).xls) the download pop-up begins appearing in the browser Selenium is driving.

```
eCaps <- list(
  chromeOptions = 
    list(prefs = list(
      "profile.default_content_settings.popups" = 0L,
      "download.prompt_for_download" = FALSE,
      "download.default_directory" = "mydownloadpath"
    )
    )
)

rd <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port=4566L, extraCapabilities = eCaps)
```

The function to download then looks like:

```
vote.downloading <- function(url){

  #NB: this function assumes browser already up and running, options set correctly

  Sys.sleep(1.5)

  browser$navigate(url)

  down_button <- browser$findElement(using="css", 
                                     "table:nth-child(4) tr:nth-child(3) a")
  down_button$clickElement()


}
```

For reference, the sites I'm getting the download from look like this: http://www.moscow_city.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/moscow_city?action=show&root=774001001&tvd=4774001137463&vrn=4774001137457&prver=0&pronetvd=null&region=77&sub_region=77&type=427&vibid=4774001137463

The link being used for the download reads "Версия для печати" for those who don't know Russian.

I can't simply stop the function when the dialog begins popping up and pick up where I left off, because it's part of a larger function that scrapes links from drop-down menus that lead to the sites from the download link. This would also be extremely annoying, as there are 400+ files to download.

Is there some way I can alter the Chrome profile or my scraping function to prevent the system dialog from popping up every 101 files? Or is there a better way altogether to get these files downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for Selenium:

```
library(httr)

httr::GET(
  url = "http://www.moscow_city.vybory.izbirkom.ru/servlet/ExcelReportVersion",
  query = list(
    region="77",
    sub_region="77",
    root="774001001",
    global="null",
    vrn="4774001137457",
    tvd="4774001137463",
    type="427",
    vibid="4774001137463",
    condition="",
    action="show",
    version="null",
    prver="0",
    sortorder="0"
  ),
  write_disk("/tmp/report.xls"), ## CHANGE ME
  verbose()
) -> res
```

I save it off to an object so you can run `warn_for_status()` or other such checks.

It shld be straightforward to wrap that in a function with parameters to make it more generic.

Comment: Fantastic! Should be easy for me to generalize this and generate meaningful file names, saving me an additional step. Out of curiosity, how did you find the  "http://www.moscow_city.vybory.izbirkom.ru/servlet/ExcelReportVersion" url?

Comment: By routing the request through https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload and inspecting the contents with https://github.com/hrbrmstr/burrp

Comment: Could you provide some more details on how to use this approach? I'm also trying to disable the pop up after the 101st download. However, I'm not sure how to approach this method.

Comment: This should be a new q @JuliusBilly

Comment: @hrbrmstr in fact, I asked it here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296807/disable-dialog-box-save-as-rselenium.